# How can I read a file in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How do I read files by line and put it into a list in kotlin? This is what I have so far, but it crashes.

```
val inputStream: InputStream = File("cards.txt").inputStream()
val lineList = mutableListOf<String>()
inputStream.bufferedReader().forEachLine { lineList.add(it) }
lineList.forEach{println(">  " + it)}
```

The error:

```
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

so I think I put the file in the wrong place. Where should i be putting it?

Comment: What is the exact error message / exception you get?

Comment: oh Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) so I think I put the file in the wrong place. Where should i be putting it?

Comment: You should supply a full path. Not only a file name.

Comment: I edited your question to put the error in it so it can be reopened. To pack a raw file with your app, put the file in a directory named `assets` in your android project module. Use `val inputStream = assets.open("cards.txt")` instead of directly using the `File` cass.